# Silent Notifications - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

Silent notifications work via Background modes and content available flag, but only if the app is in background.

Is it possible to know if/when the user received the notification, even when the app is suspended(not in background) ?

Answer (score 0):

The system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again.

Here is the relevant section from the documentation:

> *application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:*
>
> Use this method to process incoming remote notifications for your app.
>   Unlike the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method, which is
>   called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system
>   calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or
>   background. In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications
>   background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the
>   suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a push
>   notification arrives. **However, the system does not automatically
>   launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the
>   user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system
>   attempts to launch your app automatically again.**

Comment: The thing is, most users force-quit the app. So the scenario of push waking up your app works with a small percentage of users, for whom the app got quit because of memory constraint

Comment: So did you got what u were looking for ?

Comment: No. See, I know what you have mentioned above. I know how silent notifications work in background. In Android, you can know when the user has received a notification(which helps me build analytics), but there is no way in iOS, or is there? - this is the question.

Comment: :) thats the point. Even if you receive the push notification, if user has force quit the application you will never know about these noti till the time the user relaunch the app.  Hence there is no guaranteed way to achieve what u want on iOS which works in all scenario.